# Drools accumulate method that returns zero if no matching source fact

Tags: drools, accumulate

I am trying to implement a rule in Drools that calculates the sum of a some property of a fact. That works great using accumulate and sum. The problem is that when there are not fact that matches the criteria in the source part of the accumulate method the rule is not executed.

I would like the sum method to return zero if no fact is matching and that the rest of the when clauses is checked. Is that possible somehow?

Update: 
I am using Drools 6.0.1
The problem seems to lie in the the and clause. Here is a code that is my problem.

```
rule "accu"
when
$n: Number() 
   from accumulate( $o: Order() and OrderLine( $v: quantity ),
                sum($v))
then
   System.out.println("*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#* Accu has fired *#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#");
end
```

With only Order or OrderLine it works. I have a feeling I am attacking the problem the wrong way. In my real case the value I want to sum up is in the OrderLine but the criteria is in another class.

```
$ol : OrderLine($q : quantity) 
and
$ac : ArticleClass(orderLine == $ol, crtiteria1=efg, criteria2=abc)
```

Answer (score 0):

But accumulate does return 0 when there are no matching elements.

```
rule accu
when
$n: Number() 
   from accumulate( Fact( prop == "C", $v: value ),
                    sum($v))
then
   //...
end
```

This fires in the absence of Fact facts with prop == "C" and it fires if there are no Fact facts at all. (Drools 5.5.0)

Please provide full code reproducing the error, Drools version, etc.

Comment: As stated in the question, with one fact it works, but if you accumulate over two facts joined with an `and` condition then the rule doesn't fire in case of no match.